# USB Serial adapter outputs junk on loopback

Tags: drivers, usb

I've seen [USB to Serial adapter doesn't works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343522/usb-to-serial-adapter-doesnt-works), however this isn't my problem. When I plug in the adapter and start minicom, nothing works. However when I short Tx/Rx (2 and 3) then when I type characters it behaves as if I'm in VI or emacs; "j" moves down, "k" moves up, "i" tabs etc.

The output of lsusb is:

`$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:8126 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reade$
 Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 214b:7250

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

And the relevant output of dmesg is:

`[14210.926376] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[14211.055118] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523
[14211.055124] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[14211.055128] usb 3-4: Product: USB2.0-Ser!
[14211.055830] ch341 3-4:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[14211.056589] usb 3-4: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0`

Comment: Have you tried different baud rates like 9600 or 115200?

Comment: Yes. Same results.